# How to change a CSS variable unicode using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, unicode

I have a CSS variable on an element.

```
<div style="--background:example"></div>
```

The CSS variable is changed dynamically in jQuery with

```
$("div").css("--background",newValue)
```

In CSS itself, I am able to have the background dynamically change from a pseudo element like so:

```
div::after {
    content: '';
    background: var(--background);
}
```

This works fine - however, how can I go about changing the variable to different **unicodes**?

If I set `newValue` to `\f099` for example, jQuery passes it as `99`.

I have also tried `\\f099`, but that gets formatted as a literal unicode before passing and so the effects aren't applied.

If I use `\\f099`, the **CSS Inspector** displays the value of the CSS variable as a box (as if it were an actual unicode).

If I set the unicode manually in a CSS file, it displays normally, even in the inspector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you want to set the `content` to `\f099`.

The value for `content` has to be surrounded by quotes and backslash has to be escaped. Do the following:

`$("div").css("--content", '"\\f099"')`

This will set the variable to `"\f099"`.